# How to get strings which are separated with a | or ,

Tags: ruby, string

Say I have a string like a|b|c|d ... or like a,b,c,d... I want to extract a b c and d and push it in an array. What's the efficient way of doing it?

So, the input is `a|b|c|d` or `a,b,c,d` and the output should be `[a,b,c,d]`.

Answer (score 5):

The [split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) method is what you are looking for.

For example, if you want to split a string into an array of strings separated with the `|` character, you can do this:

```
"a|b|c|d".split('|')


=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

If you want to split by the string by `,` **or** `|`, you can use the same method with a regular expression:

```
"a|b|c|d".split(/\||,/)

"a,b,c,d".split(/\||,/)


=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the split function.

```
MyString.split("|")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.