# js - convert a whole array of strings into a string in which strings are separated by |

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array full of strings like `[a,b,c,d]`. I want to know the efficient way of converting this into `'a|b|c|d'` using Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the [`.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)... `['a','b','c','d'].join('|')` -> `"a|b|c|d"`

Comment: I'm really curious why you [posted a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41917687/179125) about doing the opposite in Ruby just one minute before posting this one.

Comment: haha @Jordan quite good question. 
I'm learning both ruby and Javascript and as a part of that, I'm learning strings in both.

Comment: @NinjaBoy quite honestly you should have been able to research both  easily. Research prior to asking questions here is expected

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple using [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
    var data = ['a','b','c','d'];
    console.log(data.join('|'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join),

```
var pipe_delimited_= string_array.join("|");
```

**DEMO**

```js
var string_array = ['a','b','c','d'];
var pipe_delimited = string_array.join("|");
console.log(pipe_delimited);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using array's `join()` method.The `join()` method joins array elements into a string.

```js
    var arr = ['a','b','c','d'];//your aray
    var string =arr.join("|");
    console.log(string);
```

For more see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join